# How to use orderby from another table column with C# lambda expression

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, lambda, sql-order-by

I have two tables and i need to use lambda expression to order Data from second table.

Eg: table A is linked with table B with a one to many relationship. table A's primary key will be foreign key in table B. i need to get data from both table and order by table B date time column. can someone get me an idea for this. Thank you.

A.cs file has this code,

```
public partial class A
{
    public A()
    {
      this.B = new HashSet<B>();
    }
    public virtual ICollection<B> B { get; set; }
}
```

B.cs file has this code,

```
public partial class B
{
    public Nullable<long> a_pk { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> system_date_time { get; set; }    
    public virtual A A { get; set; }
}
```

in the model, cs files have code like this. Thank you

Comment: Could you share the code for your models?

Comment: Aren't you missing an `Id` for `A`. And also - `a_pk` is a foreign key - so how can it be null?

Comment: @smoksnes Code has added to the question. thank you.

Comment: @GiladGreen yes. a_pk is a class primary key. sorry i forget to add it. thanks

Comment: Credit goes to @GiladGreen for moving the code. And about the sort. How do you visualize the output? Should `A` be sorted by `system_date_time ` in `B`? And which `B` should it be sorted by? Highest or lowest?

Comment: @smoksnes A be sorted by System_date_time in B

Comment: Yes, but if each `A` have three `B`, where each `B` have different `system_date_time`. Which `A` would then come first?

Comment: @vishwa - Basically 
1. Do you want ascending order or descending order. 2. What data do you want to select? Only A ? A and B?
3. If only A then Order asc or desc by Max/Min/What B?

Comment: @smoksnes which B's system date should be newest to oldest

Comment: @GiladGreen 1.descending order 2.any data from a, lets say a_pk. 3 Order asc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the one that worked for me.

```
var result = _context.A.Include(x => x.B).OrderByDescending(x => x.B.Max(y => y.system_date_time));
```

Thanks all

Answer (score 3):

It will probably not be very efficient, but you could do something like this:

```
// Sample data
var collection = new List<A>
{
    new A()
    {
        B = new List<B>
        {
            new B { system_date_time = DateTime.Now.AddHours(-1) },
            new B { system_date_time = DateTime.Now.AddHours(-2) },
            new B { system_date_time = DateTime.Now.AddHours(-3) },
        }
    },
    new A()
    {
        B = new List<B>
        {
            new B { system_date_time = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1) },
            new B { system_date_time = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-2) },
            new B { system_date_time = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-3) },
        }
    },
    new A()
    {
        B = new List<B>
        {
            new B { system_date_time = DateTime.Now.AddYears(-1) },
            new B { system_date_time = DateTime.Now.AddYears(-2) },
            new B { system_date_time = DateTime.Now.AddYears(-3) },
        }
    }
};


var sorted = collection.OrderByDescending(x => x.B.Max(y => y.system_date_time));
```

The SQL will be something like this:

```
Select 
    *,
    (SELECT 
        MAX([Extent2].[system_date_time]) AS [A1]
        FROM [dbo].[B] AS [Extent2]
        WHERE [Var_38].[a_pk ] = [Extent2].[a_pk ]) AS [C1]
    FROM [dbo].[A] AS [Var_38]
)  AS [Project1]
ORDER BY [C1] ASC
```

If you want `A` and include `B`, then you can do something like this:

```
var result = _context.YourATable.Include(x => x.B).OrderByDescending(x => x.B.Max(y => y.system_date_time));
```

Comment: @smoksness Thank you. I will check this too.

Comment: @GiladGreen, thank you for your edit, but now all the `B` have the same `system_date_time`, which makes it harder to verify the results.

Comment: @smoksnes - Och sorry man.. missed it. Saw the minus hours but might have missed the rest

Comment: @smoksnes include and max thing solved the problem. Thanks man

Answer (score 2):

Query syntax:

```
var result = from a in db.A
             join b in db.B on a.a_pk equals b.a_pk
             orderby b.system_date_time descending
             select new { a, b }
```

Method syntax:

```
var result = db.A.join(db.B,
                       a => a.a_pk,
                       b => b.a_pk,
                       (a,b) => new { a, b })
                 .OrderByDescending(item => item.b.system_date_time);
```

If you only want to persent items from `A` then Smoksnes answer is the way to go

Comment: @Gillad Green Thanks i will try this

Answer (score 1):

You can use SelectMany to flatten inner collection and then just iterate over plain collection and get all the info you need.
Check [this](https://dotnetfiddle.net/FcVtFe) fiddle for code.